# Jacoco coverage in Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-plugins, jacoco

Can anyone suggest if there is a way to execute Jacoco in a Jenkins Pipeline? I have downloaded the plugin but I do not get the option for Jacoco in the 'Pipeline Syntax', which is the Pipeline script help .

Referred this URL: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/JaCoCo+Plugin
which has no information for a jenkins jacoco pipeline

Comment: If your build tool is Gradle, you can do like this:

    `sh "./gradlew jacocoTestReport"`
    `publishHTML(target: [reportDir:'build/jacocoHtml', reportFiles: 'index.html', reportName: 'Code Coverage'])`

Comment: Not sure why the question is under rated. Would like to know what could be a better way to ask the question. I know how to configure the Jacoco Jenkins plugin, but could not get any information about how to do it in a pipeline. Hence I posted in this forum. Highly disappointed :(

Comment: JaCoCo is about http://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/ , so you probably get a downvote, because Jenkins JaCoCo Plugin wasn't mentioned at all initially ( http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/41893846/1 ) and so question wasn't clear. While now it is mentioned, you still can improve title and reword body.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48685604/1279002

Answer (score 35, accepted):

After trying to scour the internet for a simple example of how to do this, I eventually found the "step" tool within our Jenkins instance.

It knows how to generate snippets of Jenkinsfile pipeline code based on the plugins and modules you have installed.

The long and short of it is that the basic entry looks like:

```
stage('Build') {
     steps {
        sh './jenkins_build.sh'
        junit '*/build/test-results/*.xml'
        step( [ $class: 'JacocoPublisher' ] )
     }
}
```

The jenkins documentation really needs an update with some one-liner examples.

[image: Example from Jenkins 2.32.x]

Comment: @user5917011 Is Jacoco Report graph available on the job main page?

Comment: You forgot to tell where to put the jacoco command. Is it in a post, or inside the stage itself?

Answer (score 50):

The jacoco pipeline step configuration uses this format:

```
step([$class: 'JacocoPublisher', 
      execPattern: 'target/*.exec',
      classPattern: 'target/classes',
      sourcePattern: 'src/main/java',
      exclusionPattern: 'src/test*'
])
```

Or with a simpler syntax for declarative pipeline:

```
jacoco( 
      execPattern: 'target/*.exec',
      classPattern: 'target/classes',
      sourcePattern: 'src/main/java',
      exclusionPattern: 'src/test*'
)
```

You can find more options in the [JaCoCo Pipeline Steps Reference](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/jacoco/)

Answer (score 20):

As of the Jacoco plugin 2.2.1, you can now use `jacoco(execPattern: 'target/jacoco.exec')`

I personally have a couple of different Jacoco files for different executions and wanted to support both Maven and Gradle (so `build/` and `target/` directories), so I use `jacoco(execPattern: '**/*.exec')`.

Reference: https://github.com/jenkinsci/jacoco-plugin/pull/83

Comment: WARNING: if you do not specify a class pattern or exclusion pattern then Jenkins will include your test classes in the coverage report, which totally skew the numbers. For gradle builds this is what I am now using: `jacoco(execPattern: '**/build/jacoco/**.exec', classPattern: '**/classes/*/main')`

Answer (score 4):

If you'll have a look on a [list of plugins compatible with pipeline](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-plugin/blob/master/COMPATIBILITY.md), you'll find that Jenkins JaCoCo Plugin [was made compatible](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-27120), but without any update of documentation, except [entry in changelog](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/JaCoCo+Plugin):

> Version 2.1.0 (Sep 29, 2016)
>
> JENKINS-27120 Adding Workflow support for JaCoCo publisher

probably because its usage is simple and similar to usage of many other steps:

```
step([$class: 'JacocoPublisher', ...])
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way to use **Jacoco jenkins** plugin is to take care of generating the executable (**jacoco.exec**) in the application and then pointing the location of that file in the pipeline.
Although for a multi module project, the configuration would be slightly different, refer : [Jacoco code coverage for multi module maven project](https://pyblog.xyz/jacoco-code-coverage-for-multi-module-maven-project/)

Jenkins Pipeline would look like :

```
jacoco(
    execPattern: '**/path_to_file/jacoco.exec',
    classPattern: '**/coverage/**',
    sourcePattern: '**/coverage/**',
    inclusionPattern: '**/*.class'
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Posting one more answer since `jacoco` DSL from the accepted one did not work for me.

```
WorkflowScript: 86: Invalid parameter "execPattern", did you mean "path"? @ line 86, column 20.
               jacoco(execPattern: 'build/jacoco/test.exec')
```

I can't say exactly what set of plugins is used on my Jenkins. I only know that the version of Jenkins is 2.289.1

The following DSL for collecting coverage from the [Code Coverage API plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/code-coverage-api-plugin) worked out for me:

```
publishCoverage adapters: [jacocoAdapter('build/reports/jacoco/test/jacocoTestReport.xml')]
```