# Jenkins jacoco plugin is not obeying includes in pom.xml

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, junit, jacoco

I've got a pom.xml that looks roughly like this:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
  <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>0.8.1</version>
  <configuration>
    <includes>
      <include>my/package/path/**/*</include>
    </includes>
  </configuration>
  <!-- more stuff -->
</plugin>
```

When I run my unit tests then call `mvn jacoco:report` locally on my laptop, everything is fine, and only the stuff in `my.package.path` is included.  My coverage is 86%.  However, when I let Jenkins run the unit tests, using the same commands, then call `jacoco(execPattern:'target/jacoco.exec')` in my Jenkinsfile, I end up with all code included in the report attached to the build, so my coverage ends up being 2% because I didn't write tests for a bunch of 3rd party libraries.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You may exclude the 3rd party packages:

```
<excludes><!-- Exclude class from test coverage -->
    <exclude>**/*com/3rdparty/path/*</exclude>
</excludes>
```

Comment: doesn't resolve the issue. If jenkins isn't picking up the inclusion pattern, why would it pick up an exclusion pattern?

Comment: There are a couple of ways to exclude packages. Check the link here, see any answers would solve your problem:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27799419/maven-jacoco-configuration-exclude-classes-packages-from-report-not-working

Comment: all of these answers depend on maven and the pom.xml file. My problem relates to Jenkins seemingly not using that file.

Comment: You answered your own question. In that case, you may need to change the Jacoco configuration in Jenkins.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42265838/how-to-have-code-coverage-in-jenkins-with-jacoco-and-multiple-modules

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it by using the `inclusionPattern` parameter in the call to `jacoco`:

```
jacoco(execPattern: 'target/jacoco.exec',inclusionPattern: 'my/package/path/**/*')
```